# How do I tell the compiler that immutable references passed into a function no longer exist when another function is called for the second time?

Tags: lambda, rust, reference, lifetime, ownership

I encountered a problem with lifetimes:

```
fn solve_hanoi<'a>(
    a: &'a mut Vec<u8>,
    b: &'a mut Vec<u8>,
    c: &'a mut Vec<u8>,
    depth: u8,
    deshuffle: fn(&'a Vec<u8>, &'a Vec<u8>, &'a Vec<u8>) -> (&'a Vec<u8>, &'a Vec<u8>, &'a Vec<u8>),
) {
    if depth == 0 {
        return;
    } else {
        solve_hanoi(a, c, b, depth - 1, |a_, c_, b_| (a_, b_, c_));

        c.push(a.pop().unwrap()); // the actual move

        {
            let (a_, b_, c_) = deshuffle(a, b, c);
            print_hanoi(a_, b_, c_);
        }

        solve_hanoi(b, a, c, depth - 1, |b_, a_, c_| (a_, b_, c_));
    }
}

fn print_hanoi(_: &Vec<u8>, _: &Vec<u8>, _: &Vec<u8>) {}
```

The purpose of `deshuffle` is to make sure the printed towers are always in the same order, even when the order of values in the parameters changes. However, the compiler complains:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*b` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/lib.rs:20:9
   |
1  | fn solve_hanoi<'a>(
   |                -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
16 |             let (a_, b_, c_) = deshuffle(a, b, c);
   |                                ------------------
   |                                |            |
   |                                |            immutable borrow occurs here
   |                                argument requires that `*b` is borrowed for `'a`
...
20 |         solve_hanoi(b, a, c, depth - 1, |b_, a_, c_| (a_, b_, c_));
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*a` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/lib.rs:20:9
   |
1  | fn solve_hanoi<'a>(
   |                -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
16 |             let (a_, b_, c_) = deshuffle(a, b, c);
   |                                ------------------
   |                                |         |
   |                                |         immutable borrow occurs here
   |                                argument requires that `*a` is borrowed for `'a`
...
20 |         solve_hanoi(b, a, c, depth - 1, |b_, a_, c_| (a_, b_, c_));
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*c` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/lib.rs:20:9
   |
1  | fn solve_hanoi<'a>(
   |                -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
16 |             let (a_, b_, c_) = deshuffle(a, b, c);
   |                                ------------------
   |                                |               |
   |                                |               immutable borrow occurs here
   |                                argument requires that `*c` is borrowed for `'a`
...
20 |         solve_hanoi(b, a, c, depth - 1, |b_, a_, c_| (a_, b_, c_));
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

I tried various different combinations of lifetime annotations, but there was always some problem. How do I tell the compiler that the immutable references that are passed into the `deshuffle` function no longer exist when `solve_hanoi` is called for the second time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `'a` as lifetime of the function arguments as well as for `a`, `b` and `c`. This means that the function borrows the arguments until the end of their own lifetime. Instead, you probably want the function arguments and return values to have their own lifetime:

```rust
fn solve_hanoi<'a>(
    a: &'a mut Vec<u8>,
    b: &'a mut Vec<u8>,
    c: &'a mut Vec<u8>,
    depth: u8,
    deshuffle: for<'b> fn(
        &'b Vec<u8>,
        &'b Vec<u8>,
        &'b Vec<u8>,
    ) -> (&'b Vec<u8>, &'b Vec<u8>, &'b Vec<u8>),
) {
    if depth == 0 {
        return;
    } else {
        solve_hanoi(a, c, b, depth - 1, |a_, c_, b_| (a_, b_, c_));

        c.push(a.pop().unwrap()); // the actual move

        {
            let (a_, b_, c_) = deshuffle(a, b, c);
            // print_hanoi(a_, b_, c_);
        }

        solve_hanoi(b, c, a, depth - 1, |b_, c_, a_| (a_, b_, c_));
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=918f0c8ec2425849dbe306a67c52f31b)